# Getting frames from Video Windows Phone. FFmpeg Wrapper

Tags: bitmap, ffmpeg, windows-phone, gif, frames

I`m actually writing Application to make and edit GIFs from Video on Windows Phone 8.1. I`d like to get an array of Bitmaps from MediaClip(can be saved as videofile). I could use AForge, but it`s just for x86 only. I also tried using Lumia.Imaging, but not sure it can do what I want. 
I know FFMpeg is doing somethong like that, but I dont need to just save frames, but to use them as Bitmap array to then use every Bitmap as ByteArray.

Here I read that there is absolutely no way to do what I want without writing my own code. Is it true?
[Accessing & Manipulating video frames from .mp4 file in Windows Phone 7 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12189764/accessing-manipulating-video-frames-from-mp4-file-in-windows-phone-7-app)

Thank you for any help. Ask for more detailed info.